# Count the frequency of two linked columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas

So, this is my problem. I have two columns:

```
level | people
 low  | person1
 low  | person1
 high | person1
 high | person2
medium| person2
```

And i want to write in another cell a table like that:

```
people |low|medium|high|
person1 | 2 |   0  |  1 |
person2 | 0 |   1  |  1 |
```

I'm trying to use pandas(groupby, value_count...) and openpyxl, but nothing seens to work, and a cant do it manually because it's a sheet with a thousand values. Please, help.

Comment: Could you show some sample data please? Construct a smaller version of the data structure in Python, then print it with `print(repr(my_variable))`, and show us the result. (Or just crop your Excel file to 4 or 5 values and import the cropped version, then show us the pandas variable.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a good use of `pivot_table`

```
df.pivot_table(columns='level', index='people', aggfunc='size').fillna(0)
```

Comment: one suggestion to not add a new column: `df.pivot_table(index='people', columns='level', aggfunc=lambda x: x['level'].count())`

Comment: Better yet, avoid the `lambda`: `df.pivot_table(columns='level', index='people', aggfunc='size').fillna(0)`

Comment: Nice @ALollz!  Editing answer to match

Comment: @ALollz even better, Love it...going to be faster than lambda

Comment: @Chris Though I think the fastest solution to these problems is still `groupby` + `unstack`: `df.groupby(['people', 'level']).size().unstack().fillna(0).astype(int)`. Typically beats `.pivot_table` and `crosstab` is always slower for some reason.

Comment: Thanks, guys. It works!!! In my IDLE it prints a table with six columns. How do i append all the columns to the excel sheet?